# OperationalError no such table: categories_article

Tags: python, django

When i enter django admin interface and click  "Articles"   i got Error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/categories/article/
no such table: categories_article
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/categories/article/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: categories_article
Exception Location: \Envs\django19\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 323
Python Executable:  \Envs\django19\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Article


admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Article)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=20000)
```

What should i do to create new "Article" object in django admin?

Comment: Not sure but have you tried to run `manage.py makemigrations`and `manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: Yes, there is "No migrations to apply"

Comment: Have you ever had any problem with migrations? Do you have a migrations folder in your app ? Do you see the table when you look directly in the database ?

Comment: Thanks.Yes i had, but i don't know what exactly (I'm beginner). I create new project and copy all stuff there and didn't get any error again. So i think this post can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your migrations but it is difficult to say which file is causing the migration error. You have to check each migration file in **migrations** directory. It basically occurs because you have a migration in which you have already created the table **Articles** and somehow django skipped that migration, created the new migration file and marked previous migration as successful. Try one of these ways

1) One way of doing this is find the migration file that creates **Article** table, delete that migration file and change the dependency of the next migration file to the previous migration file or else django will throw an error. And then:

```
python manage makemigrations
python manage migrate
```

2) Change the name of Model **Article** to something else like **Articles** and then run migration commands:

```
python manage makemigrations
python manage migrate
```

3) If none of the above works. This sure will. Delete all migration and rerun all the migrations.